# A disabled checkbox can still be checked in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox

I have a check box in my page as follows:

```
  <asp:CheckBox ID="chkPayerCB" 
    runat="server" 
    Text="Payer Core Banking details" 
    TextAlign="Right"/>
```

I need to disable it on Page Load event of the page. I wrote the following code in code behind:

```
 chkPayerCB.Enabled = false;
```

Though the check box is disabled but it still gets checked for a moment on clicking at it and then gets unchecked.
Though it solves my purpose but I do not want it to be checked at any cost.

I am using VS 2008 Professional Edition (v 9.0.2). Please can anybody guide me on this.

Comment: are u using update panel?? can you post your code?

Comment: @KeerthiKumar I am not using update panel. What other code you want? Please let me know.

Comment: i want asp design code

Comment: @KeerthiKumar the problem has been resolved. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a different approach.

Set `Enabled = False` in the `Designer`.

If you need to enable it under some circustances you can use `Page_Load` event.

Comment: Amazingly it did work with the designer. Thanks. It was so simple. :D